# How to create a function that pushes Objects into an array, when pushed again it will add the additional obj

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, push, formgroups

I am trying to add a user object to an array to eventually submit a list of users.

```
I have declared the following:
people: any[];
person = {
       name:'',
       age: ''
       }
```

I am using a formbuilder.group to collect the name and age of the person successfully (this is done in the ngOnInit(). However I am struggling to add more than one person to the people array.
I have tried the following:

```
addPerson() {
    let person = this.peopleForm.value;
    this.people.push({name: person.name, age: person.age});
}
```

I'm using { players | json } to display the captured values, however when i use the form again after a successful addPerson() click, the added values get updated NOT added.

Expected behaviour:

Upon entering a new name and details the new object must be pushed into the people array so it will display the newly added persons i.e

```
people[
      {name: firstSubmittionName, age: firstSubmittionName},
      {name: secondSubmittionName, age: secondSubmittionName} 
      ]

<form (ngSubmit)="addEvent(f)" #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="eventForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name of person</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          formControlName="name"
          class="form-control"
        />
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="attendingState">User attending status</label>
          <select
            class="form-control"
            name="state"
            id="state"
            formControlName="state"
          >
            <option *ngFor="let state of attendingState [ngValue]="state">
              {{ state }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button (click)="addConfirmed()">
        Add Player
      </button>
      Value: {{ people | json }}
    </form>
```

I'm using Angular 7. Please let me know if i need to provide lil or loads more details to my question thanks. I'm assuming that i'll need to add an index to avoid duplications/updates? not sure.

**Good news**, I think i understand the problem i was facing it was about immutability, i have implemented the following to resolve my issue:

```
addConfirmed() {
    let group = [];
    let person = this.eventForm.value;
    group.push( person );
    let newArray = this.people;
     if( newArray === undefined){
       this.players = group; 
     } else {
         this.players = group.concat(newArray);
         console.log('this is the group value ', this.people);
}
}
```

I needed to use a new array in my function to make the arrays i'm using immutable.

Comment: can you try updating the addPerson's second line with this:
 `this.people.push(...person);` and tell me what happens

Comment: can you show html?

Comment: Silvan Bregy i've added the html. @FranciscoSantorelli i have also tried with the spread operator, this still gave me the same results.

Comment: `push` is mutating. you need an immutable operation on the array if you want to see it updated

Comment: @Antonis I think it does have something to do with me mutating my values, do you have a sample i could have a look at?

Comment: @tony2tones check the answer below. hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`this.people = [...this.people, person]`

Comment: curious re spread operator before ‘person’. I think you meant to only use spread operator before this.people here. why use it with person obj?

Comment: typo. should be a comma before person

Comment: thought so;) agreed i would do the same to create new array